# Python 3 finding multiple words in a .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hi I am creating a troubleshooting program and I have a partial working solution, if a user types in a single word problem the word is found in the csv then the correct advice is output. However the problem is if multiple words are input by a user nothing is found and no advice is output at all, the program stops.

```
import csv
import webbrowser

print("Hello! Welcome to trouble shooter 2.0")

def menu():
    try:
        Phone = int(input("""What is your operating system?
    Please choose the corresponding number:
    1) iOS
    2) Android
    3) Other
    > """))

        if Phone == 1:
            print("Thank you iOS user")
        elif Phone == 2:
            print("Thank you Android user")
        elif Phone == 3:
            print("Thank you")
        else:
            print("please find out")
            exit()
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter a numerical input")
        menu()

menu()


task2 = open ("problem list.csv")
Problem = input ("""Please enter the issue you wish to resolve
>""")
KeyWords = Problem.split()
reader = csv.reader(task2, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    if Problem == row[0]:
            print(row[1])
    else:
        print("we do not have an answer for this")


helpful = input("""


Was this helpful?""").lower()
if helpful[0] == 'n':
    google = input("in this case, please input your issue, for a google   search: ")
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&q=%s'% google)

elif helpful[0] == 'y':
    print("""
You are welcome""")
    exit()
```

Comment: You already split the user input to individual keywords - try to use them!

Answer (score 0):

the  issue is with **if Problem == row[0]:** , Problem is the return value of the split function which is a list .So you should check every value in the list which means you should use `if row in Keywords :` .

I did not tested it yet theoretically it should work !

Comment: In python3.x `input` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a `string`,so there is no need to use `str()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot this

```
KeyWords = Problem.split()
```

Actually you can use `KeyWords` instead of `Problem`,because it seems that `row[0]` is a word,and the type of `KeyWords` now is `list` ,so why don't you try this:

```
    if row[0] in KeyWords:
            print(row[1])
```

Try to debug it and you will find what's wrong with your code.

Hope this helps.